# Why is Test::WWW::Mechanize::PSGI using a port?

Tags: perl, catalyst, plack, psgi

I have some code that looks like this:

```
use SomeApp;
use Test::WWW::Mechanize::PSGI;                                                                                                                                         
my $mech = Test::WWW::Mechanize::PSGI->new(
    app  => sub { SomeApp->run(@_) },
);
$mech->get_ok('/');
```

However, as soon as `get_ok()` is called, I get the following warning:

```
PSGI error: failed to listen to port 8080: Address already in use at .../5.18.1/HTTP/Server/PSGI.pm line 94.
HTTP::Server::PSGI::setup_listener('HTTP::Server::PSGI=HASH(0x7fe6622fad60)') called at .../5.18.1/HTTP/Server/PSGI.pm line 54
```

And yes, I'm using that port for something else. From [the docs of Test::WWW::Mechanize::PSGI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-WWW-Mechanize-PSGI/lib/Test/WWW/Mechanize/PSGI.pm):

> This module allows you to test PSGI web applications but does not require a server or issue HTTP requests. Instead, it passes the HTTP request object directly to PSGI.

So in theory, I shouldn't need to specify a port, but I get the above warning and pages fetched return a 500 (they work fine in the browser). What am I missing?

- Test::WWW::Mechanize::PSGI version 0.35
- Plack version 1.0030
- Catalyst version 5.90051

Changing `MyApp->run` to `MyApp->psgi_app` results in:

```
Can't call method "request" on an undefined value at .../5.18.1/Test/WWW/Mechanize/PSGI.pm line 47.
```

This error can be replicated with:

```
catalyst.pl MyApp
cd MyApp
# run the test program above
```

Comment: I'm not sure what `SomeApp` contains, but have you ever tried `Plack::Util::load_psgi`?  `my $mech = Test::WWW::Mechanize::PSGI->new(app => Plack::Util::load_psgi('SomeApp'));`

Comment: emix: that generates `Error while loading MyApp.pm: Setting config after setup has been run is not allowed` even with a plain `catalyst.pl SomeApp`. I've posted a workaround as an answer. Also, if I wrap it in a sub (required) and remove the "use SomeApp", I get `Can't call method "request" on an undefined value`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Catalyst's `run` method would actually run the HTTP server (via Plack/PSGI!) for a development, which is not what you want with testing via PSGI (without running a server). You need: `app => MyApp->psgi_app`, without an extra `sub` block, since `psgi_app` supposedly returns the PSGI app itself.

The error message "Can't call method 'request' on ..." is a common error when your app returns something that is not correct per PSGI spec. The message has been improved a bit on the git master, but it's essentially a user error since you're basically returning `sub { $app }` when it expects just `$app`.

More documentation on the PSGI support with Catalyst is available with `perldoc Catalyst::PSGI`.

Comment: Thank you. Using `MyApp->psgi_app` without the sub solved it. This is a legacy application I've been trying to upgrade, as you speculated on Twitter, and there are many tiny changes like this I'm finding.

Answer (score 4):

Matt Trout mentioned `LWP::Protocol::PSGI` as a workaround. It hijacks HTTP to make this work:

```
use Test::WWW::Mechanize;
use LWP::Protocol::PSGI;
use MyApp;

LWP::Protocol::PSGI->register( MyApp->psgi_app(@_) );
my $mech = Test::WWW::Mechanize->new;

# first GET must be absolute
$mech->get('http://localhost/login');
say $mech->content;

# then we can switch to relative
$mech->get('/login');
say $mech->content;
```

In short, the above is more or less cargo-culted (as I don't understand why the first version failed), but it's enough for me to move forward.